# How to reference SQL Server in another resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I have an application which consists of 2 web applications with a SQL database for each. The plan is to put each web application and its DB into a separate resource group. The shared SQL Server will be in its own resource group.

How can I reference the shared SQL Server in the Azure Resource Manager template of a web application?

I already tried the following:

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": { },
      "variables": { },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlserver-dev/databases/app1db",
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [ ],
          "properties": {
            "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
            "edition": "Basic",
            "maxSizeBytes": "1073741824",
            "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "Basic"
           }
        }
      ]
    }
```

But this approach gives me the error:

```
Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlserver-dev/databases/app1db' for type 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases' at line '1' and column '202' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.
```

When I use the resourceId of the SQL server:

```
/subscriptions/{GUID}/resourceGroups/sql-server-group/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlserver-dev/databases/app1db
```

I get the same error.

Any ideas how to establish the cross-resource-group link?

Comment: Why do you need to reference from the ARM template, vs just... connecting to the database?

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I need to reference the SQL Server when I want to provision the SQL Database to the app resource group.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign an Azure SQL server and its databases to different resource groups.